# jquery autocomplete doesn't display any result

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

the html code is way too long to copy and paste on stackoverflow so I'm just gonna link [my site](http://50.116.7.88/designers.html). If you go to the site, you will see the search bar above some designer names. basically I'm trying to implement autocomplete using jquery-ui plugin. and It doesn't show any result below the search bar. I've never used this plugin so I literally have no idea why this doesn't work.

I'm handling the autocomplete part in `/js/autocomplete.js`. There's not much code in it. data and adding to event listener. that's it.

```
let designers = [ .. ] // click to see whole data

$(function() {
    $('#keyword').autocomplete({
        source: designers,
        minLength: 6
    })
})
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: It Works for me. Screen shot: https://screencast.com/t/s8wdK7S9fRVI

Comment: @OfirBaruch It does work in my website? I don't get why It's not working for me even though I'm using latest version of chrome

Comment: @OfirBaruch damn, probably because of cache

Comment: @OfirBaruch just cleared browser cache, still doesn't work. so weird

Comment: Maybe it's a timing issue. Lets debug it:
Use document.ready() and try to use 'var' instead of 'let' and put it inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when pressing on search input you have error in console which leading to this place in your code. That's why autocomplete doesn't work.

```
$(".m4").click(function(event){            
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
   });
```

Comment: I don't think you find the right element. the search bar is #keyword

Answer (score 0):

Try JQuery UI autocomplete (https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default)

Comment: It's the one OP use.

Comment: In jQuery UI we choose one option. but there is an option to search. If you don't like it here is another option for you https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage

Comment: And you have another issue in your website you have horizontal scroll in it and items outside of container

Answer (score 0):

It does for me... 
You've got minLength of 6 there meaning it won't search through the array until you've typed 6 characters, tried running the code with out the minLength parameter and worked as expected